# How do I render an image using map function?

Tags: image, react-native, url, rendering, map-function

I've tried do render the image from URL but I have no success. If write the URI ok, but if I write `item.show.image.original.replace ('http:', 'https:')` to get the image no success.

The problem is there´s no error but not rendering.

The others values I've had success with.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

let termo = 'batman';
const API = 'http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q='+termo;

export default class mapFunction extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [], };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ array: data}));
  }

  list = () => {
    return this.state.array.map(item => {
      return (
      <View style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
                   <Text>{item.score}</Text>
                   <Text>{item.show.name}</Text>
                   <Text>{item.show.type}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.show.language}</Text>
                   <Text>{item.show.summary} </Text>
                  <Image source={{uri:'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/6/16463.jpg'}}
                  style={{width:90, height:150}} />
       </View>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <View>{this.list()}
   
     </View>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change **render** function as below:

```
render() {
    return (
       <View>{this.list()}</View>
    );
}
```